# Binary linked against different shared libraries of the same package

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers, dynamic-linking

I have 2 shared libraries conflicting with each other, and other binaries linked against them. To be more detailed, I have something like this:

- **top-lib1.so** linked with **libprotobuf.so**;
- **top-lib2.so** linked with **libprotobuf-lite.so**;
- **binary** linked with **top-lib1.so** and **top-lib2.so**.

The problem is that when I launch my **binary**, I have crash due to some memory corruption caused by double-free: the first from **protobuf.so** and the second from **protobuf-lite.so** (see [related bug](http://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/44)).

I haven't access to **top-lib2.so** sources, and I can't link **top-lib1.so** with **protobuf-lite.so** due to my app functionality.

Thus my question is: how to deal with it?

I can't leave both due to this crash, I can't re-link my lib (**top-lib1.so**) with **libprotobuf-lite.so**, and I can't change **top-lib2.so**.

Is there any way to re-link  **top-lib2.so** with **libprotobuf.so** without sources? Or is there any other possibility?

Comment: Usually shared libraries which depend on other shared libraries do not link their dependents at all.  Meaning you'd only need to link your executable against `libprotobuf.so` and it should all just work.  Can you run `ldd top-lib1.so` and `ldd top-lib2.so` and show us if they are actually linked against either protobuf library?  And show us your link command line for the final executable.

Comment: @John Zwinck: `ldd top-lib2.so | grep proto`: *libprotobuf-lite.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9 (0x00007fa17d190000)*; `ldd top-lib1.so | grep proto`: *libprotobuf.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9 (0x00007f9431d94000)*; **final executable**: `g++ -o test test.cpp -ltop-lib2.so -ltop-lib1.so`; `ldd test | grep proto`: *libprotobuf.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9 (0x00007fe639b24000);
libprotobuf-lite.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9 (0x00007fe625b0a000)*

Comment: What are your linker command lines?  For `top-lib1.so` and the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a few choices.

The upstream bug you mentioned states that "`libprotobuf.so` has everything `libprotobuf-lite.so` has, and more". If that is indeed the case, one possible solution is to binary-patch `top-lib2.so`'s `.dynamic` section to reference `libprotobuf.so` instead of the `-lite.so`. The former is shorter, so simply overwriting the string `libprotobuf-lite.so` with `libprotobuf.so\0e.so` is all you should need.

If you don't want to binary-patch `top-lib2.so`, you have other choices:

1. You could link in all of `top-lib1.so` comprising object files *and* all of `libprotobuf.so` ones into the main binary and hide all `libprotobuf`'s symbols in it (via linker script). If you do that, `top-lib2.so` *can't tell* that there is anything except `libprotobuf-lite.so` which it expects.
2. You could do the same with `top-lib1.so` -- i.e. *hide* `libprotobuf` inside of it.
3. You could link your copy of `libprotobuf.so` with `-Wl,--default-symver`, which will append `@@libprotobuf.so` version to every symbol exported from `libprotobuf.so`, and avoid the symbol collision that causes the problem in the first place.

Comment: The problem is not in symbol collision. The problem is that resulting binary **calls** some tear-down function **twice**, and **libprotobuf** simply can't handle this situation. I'm not even sure that linking to the same library will help to fix the problem. But thanks, you answered my question.

Comment: @avtomaton I don't believe you understand the problem. Calling tear-down function twice on *separate* objects is fine. Calling it on the *same* object is not. The two libraries try to tear down the *same* object *precisely* because of (global variable) symbol collision.